# How can I put Windows Server 2008 into sleep mode?

Tags: sleep, windows-server-2008

I have Windows Server 2008 and I tried to put it into sleep mode at night. But I could not find it.

Is there any way to make it sleep or turn off the hard disk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not enabled by default on Windows Server 2008, servers by nature aren't usually put to sleep like desktop machines, but it is easily enabled:

> 1. Click Start, click Control Panel, and then double-click Power Options.
> 2. Under the power plan that is configured, click Change plan
>      settings, and then click Change
>      advanced power settings.
> 3. Expand Sleep, and then modify the sleep configuration settings as
>      appropriate for your requirements.
>
> **Note**: If Sleep does not appear on the Advanced Settings tab of the Power
>   Options dialog box, the computer does
>   not meet the requirements to support
>   the sleep feature. In this scenario,
>   you may have to update the drivers or
>   the devices on the computer.

[Related MSKB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947036).